Serialize to String (unwrap) instead of JSON object when only the object's key property is set
Consider this Class (lombok used):
@Data
@Builder
public class Metric
{
   private String name;

   private SortedSet<Integer> filters;

   @JsonCreator
   public Metric (String name, SortedSet<Integer> filters)
   {
      this.name = name;
      this.filters = filters;
   }

   @JsonCreator (mode = JsonCreator.Mode.DELEGATING)
   public Metric (String name)
   {
      this.name = name;
   }

Using the Annotation JsonCreator.Mode.DELEGATING I can successfully deserialize my Object from a string instead of an JSON-Object:
[
  { "name": "simplemetric1" },
  "simplemetric2",
  { "name": "filteredmetric", "filters": [ 1, 2, 3, 90 ] },
  "simplemetric4"
]

But how can I automatically serialize to a string when only a specific field (in this case name) is set? The only way I figured out is to write a custom serializer:
   static final class MetricSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Metric>
   {
      private final JsonSerializer<?> defaultSerializer;

      public MetricSerializer (JsonSerializer<?> defaultSerializer)
      {
         this.defaultSerializer = defaultSerializer;
      }

      @Override
      public void serialize (Metric value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException
      {
         if (value.getFilters () == null)
         {
            // serialize name-field only
            serializers.defaultSerializeValue (value.getName (), gen);
         }
         else
         {
            // use default serializer:
            ((JsonSerializer<Object>) defaultSerializer).serialize (value, gen, serializers);
         }
      }
   }

This has the drawback that I need to maintain this serializer when I add more properties to Metric. Does Jackson have a better/integrated mechanism for this?
